# SQL Error #1064 - PHP code

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

I'm just learning SQL in context to PHP and I have problem.
I made this code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define ( 'MYSQL_HOST',      'localhost' );
define ( 'MYSQL_BENUTZER',  'dvd' );
define ( 'MYSQL_KENNWORT',  'abc' );
define ( 'MYSQL_DATENBANK', 'benutzer' );

#establish connection
$db_link = mysqli_connect (
                 MYSQL_HOST, 
                 MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                 MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                 MYSQL_DATENBANK
                );


$abfrage = "USE benutzer; SELECT `code`, `used` FROM `keys` WHERE `code` LIKE '$key'";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis)
OR die("Error: $ergebnis <br>".mysql_error());
```

I want to have an system with one time keys and with thich I'll fatch the data, for looking if they are already used.
With this code, php shows me this errors:

```
Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvds\administration\auth.php on line 8
Warning: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\dvds\administration\auth.php on line 9

Error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT `key`, `used` FROM `keys` WHERE `key` LIKE 'KjAvkSpUwJCdNjfTEDfRDUrVmGXBH' at line 1*

Please help me!!
```

Comment: mysql_query only accepts one query at a time,you already have defined the db in the connection,remove USE benutzer,Putting aside the deprecated function

Comment: Use mysqli_query please. All mysql-functions are deprecated, use mysqli instead

Comment: MySQLi : http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
PDO : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I like how you completely ignored the deprecation warning.

Comment: I had already changed the API to mysqli, but it also shows this errors. This is why, I have ignored that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to write `USE benutzer;`
Database is already selected via `mysqli_connect`

Also you're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` API's. These are absolutely different APIs and `mysql` is **DEPRECATED**.

Answer (score 0):

You connected with mysqli_connect but you use mysql_query,
can you try `mysqli_query`

Comment: You must convert all mysql commands to mysqli  . examples:http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php